# Wordpress admin: post ID changes in featured image metabox

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-admin

I'm adding options to the "Featured image" metabox when editing a post. From within the metabox I need to access the post ID. This works fine when post.php first loads. However, if I either "Select featured image" or "Remove featured image", the post ID changes (to the static home page ID) when the metabox reloads.

Here is some code that will display the post ID in the featured image box:

```
add_filter( 'admin_post_thumbnail_html', 'add_options_to_featured_image' );
function add_options_to_featured_image( $html ){
    global $post;

    $html .= '<label>Post '.$post->ID.'</label>';

    return $html;
}
```

These are the steps to reproduce what I'm seeing:

1. Edit a post
2. Notice that the post ID is correct (e.g. 7)
3. Click "Select featured image" and select an image
4. The metabox refreshes to show the select image
5. Note that the post ID is now incorrect (the ID of the static front page)

My question: How can I consistently get the ID of the page being edited from within the featured image metabox? I'd like to try and avoid javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I consistently get the ID of the page being edited from within
>   the featured image metabox?

Set the `function` to accept two arguments, like so:

```
add_filter( 'admin_post_thumbnail_html', 'add_options_to_featured_image', 10, 2 );
function add_options_to_featured_image( $html, $post_id ){
    $html .= '<label>Post '.$post_id.'</label>';

    return $html;
}
```

See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_post_thumbnail_html/ for more info.